Angular Errors during JIT compilation when upgrading to Angular 15 to Angular 18
I have just been upgrading a project form Angular 15 to Angular 18 and ran into a bunch of JIT errors when running my unit tests as follows
Errors during JIT compilation of template for _CdkTable: Unexpected character "EOF" (Do you have an unescaped "{" in your template? 
Use "{{ '{' }}") to escape it.) ("
        <ng-container noDataRowOutlet/>
        <ng-container footerRowOutlet/>
      }
    [ERROR ->]"): ng:///_CdkTable/ɵcmp.js@29:0, Invalid ICU message. Missing '}'. ("
        <ng-container noDataRowOutlet/>
        <ng-container footerRowOutlet/>
      }
    [ERROR ->]"): ng:///_CdkTable/ɵcmp.js@29:0
      11 |   provideMagicalMock,
      12 | } from '@xxxxxxxx';

These tests used to run successfully prior to build.
Theres a similar question here in stackoverflow but in my case I dont have any html-loader as provieded in the answer
Angular Errors during JIT compilation when upgrading to Angular 13 with webpack

Did you use ng update to run the migration scripts?

@JSONDerulo No I just cleared node_modules and cleaned cache and ran npm install

Always use ng update to perform Angular major updates, see https://angular.dev/update-guide.
In this particular case, Angular 17 changed the handling of brace characters in templates due to the implementation of control flow. Make sure you are replacing literal usages of the { or } character with the corresponding HTML entities &#123; or &#125;. Alternatively, you can try to run the block syntax template entities migration, however it only exists in Angular 17 (Or perform the update from v16 to v17 with ng update which will run this migration automatically).

Thanks for the response. I missed to mention that I am working in a Nx monorepo workspace so I cant explicitly use ng update as it wont work however, I ran command npx nx migrate latest equivalent to ng update
